# how to make this javascript array value loop and stop at the last index

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, setinterval

i have this script which count values one at a time out of javascript array, but the problem is when the last when it count to the last index it starts from index 0 again, but i want it to stop at the last index. am using setInterval to make it run continuesly. here is my code so far:
i appreciate your time. thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>my page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Counter</h4>
  <span id="disp"></span>

  <script>
    var title = ['$0', '$30', '$47', '$257', '$657', '$1389', '$1557', '$2557'];

    var i = 0; // the index of the current item to show

    setInterval(function() { // setInterval makes it run repeatedly
      document
        .getElementById('disp')
        .innerHTML = title[i++]; // get the item and increment i to move to the next
      if (i == title.length) i = 0; // reset to first element if you've reached the end
    }, 3000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the interval id and if you are finished call `clearInterval` with it to stop the interval.

```html
<h4>Counter</h4>

<span id="disp"></span>

<script>
  var title = ['$0', '$30', '$47', '$257', '$657', '$1389', '$1557', '$2557'];

  var i = 0; // the index of the current item to show

  var interval = setInterval(function() { // setInterval makes it run repeatedly
    document
      .getElementById('disp')
      .innerHTML = title[i++]; // get the item and increment i to move to the next
    if (i == title.length) {
      i = 0; // reset to first element if you've reached the end
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 300);
</script>
```